# Dynamically creating a excel sheet with current time stamp using SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I have a table with 3 columns. I need to import this table's data into an Excel sheet. I need to create the Excel sheet dynamically name and timestamp. Is there any reference for this procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to name the Excel file just as a date/time stamp, you can set this up in the SSIS variables.

Create a variable for the path, I've named it ExcelFilePath and set it to C:\Temp\ . Create another called ExcelFileName, and then go into the expression editor, and enter the following:

@[User::ExcelFilePath] + LEFT((DT_WSTR, 30)GETDATE(), 19)

Here's an image of how it should look:

[image: Expression editor creating timestamp]

You can then create an Excel Connection Manager, go into the Properties for it, and click the ... button on the Expressions property. A windows will open - under Property select ExcelFilePath, and then click the ... button in the Expression column next to it:

[image: Excel connection manager expressions dialogue]

The expression editor will open again, this time enter @[User::ExcelFilePath], like this:

[image: Expression editor setting path]

You may need to set up more dynamic parts in the Control Flow or Data Flow if you want to name the file with a dynamic name followed by the timestamp, but you can use the variables in exactly the same way as I've shown here. Likewise, if the path needs to be dynamic, you can set that variable via a script in the Control Flow or Data Flow.

Answer (score 1):

Below link might help you:
[Dynamically creating Excel File, ExcelSheets](http://dwhanalytics.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/ssis-dynamically-generate-excel-tablesheet/)